# Grouping in dataframe dataset - every X years

Tags: python

I have a a timeseries data set from 1980 to 2018 and I want to do a summary statistics (ex. mean) for every 5 years. Is there a code for this?

I've tried doing this but I'm seeing below error. (The year is set as the index)

```
N = 5
df['salary'].groupby(df.index // N).mean()
```

TypeError: cannot perform **floordiv** with this index type: DatetimeIndex

Comment: `df.index.year // N`?

Comment: Hi Lara, can you please be more clear, put your dataset input and what you expect  as the output.